# How to set the apple watch icon image in iOS

Tags: ios, watchkit, apple-watch

[image]

[image]

I want to add the apple watch app icon image in Glance option shown in iPhone(Please refer attached image).I have added all the appIcon images shown in asset file. But icon image is not visible in iPhone for glance option. So where to add icon image for this ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you add all the appIcon images to asset file? It seems empty (your attached image)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have added all the images into watch app asset file. Below are the files I have added in asset file                                            24pt = 48x48px
27.5pt = 55x55px
29pt@2x = 58x58px
29pt@3x = 87x87px
40pt@2x = 80x80px
44pt = 88x88px
86pt = 172x172px
98pt = 196x196px                                                                                                         As its client project thats why I attached empty asset file

Comment: @Rushikesh Did you find a solution for this issue at the end?

Answer (score 0):

2 Points:

1. Make sure that you have added your app icon in XCAsset of "ProjectName WatchKit App" folder.
2. Turn on car play as well. (I am not sure if it is required, but you can try.)

Comment: Yes I have added images in Assets.xcassets under Watch app project. I have tried by adding carplay icon images but not success. Image is still not showing

Answer (score 0):

Just as an fyi make sure all icons are .png format and de-interlaced. Also no transparency on the Home Screen icon.

Answer (score 0):

It may be a bit unclear, because if you use a standard XCode template App, you may find two Assets.xcassets. The first would be under the WatchKit App and the second one under the Watch Kit Extension, usually where you insert your code logic.

Well, check out the **Assets.xcassets under the WatchKit App group-folder, that’s the one.** You will find in this image assets the AppIcon group, fill the icons and you are good to go.

Original source:
https://www.jazzcoding.com/locate-real-watch-icons-assets/